# Does the Cassandra Java driver have knowledge of port 7000?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-driver

Typically port 9042 is provided with the Cassandra cluster seed hosts to connect to Cassandra cluster for performing CRUD operations.

Does Cassandra Java client driver has knowledge of port 7000 (used for peer communication) after the client establishes connection with Cassandra cluster?

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java driver doesn't make use of the internode communication port `7000` because it doesn't need to participate in gossip with the nodes in the cluster.

Instead, the Java driver establishes a **control connection** with one of the nodes the first time it connects to the cluster. The driver uses the control connection (1) to query the system tables to discover the cluster's topology and schema, and (2) listen to topology and schema changes.

It is in point (2) above that the driver recognises when nodes are added or decommissioned from the cluster as well as find out when the schema has been updated. This is the reason the driver doesn't need to gossip with the nodes.

For more information, see [Control connection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/control_connection/) for the Java driver. Cheers!

Comment: This answer is an example of a good answer and should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Java driver doesn't know and should not know about in-cluster node-to-node communications. Why should it, anyway?